# Handling two fragments in two different activities in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have two activities, each having one fragment loading in them.
In first activity, I have a fragment which has a list view and when I click List view item it takes me to another activity using Intent. The fragments loads on the 2nd activity.
Till here it works fine.

Now when I click device's back button, to again go back to list view, I have to click 2 to 3 times to go to previous list view activity, the 2nd activity or fragment reloads several times before I return to first activity.

Not able to understand the issue.

Thanks in advance!!!

In first activity , this is how I'm loading the fragement

```
fragment = new GrowSapceTutorialFragment();
                   fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();




fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container_grow_tutorial, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

For the back button in 1st activity:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
```

In growspaceTutorialfragment under oncreate viewenter code here:

```
  listViewTip.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                for(int i=0; i<=position;i++){

                    name = dataModelArrayList.get(position).getTitle().toString();
                    description = dataModelArrayList.get(position).getDescription().toString();
                    image = dataModelArrayList.get(position).getImageUrl().toString();
                    tipIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), TipDetailsActivity.class);
                    tipIntent.putExtra("Title",name);
                    tipIntent.putExtra("Des", description);
                    tipIntent.putExtra("Image", image);
                startActivity(tipIntent);
```

In my Tip details Activity(2nd Activity):

```
tipImage = findViewById(R.id.tipImageView);

        title = getIntent().getStringExtra("Title");
        description = getIntent().getStringExtra("Des");
        image = getIntent().getStringExtra("Image");
        Picasso.get().load(image).into(tipImage);

       bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Title",title);
        bundle.putString("Des", description);


        fragment = new TipDetailsFragment();
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.attach(fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Tip Details Activity the back button is handled by:

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Tip Details Fragment:

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tip_details, container, false);
        title = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTipTitle);
        description = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
        bundle = getArguments();
        tipTitle = bundle.getString("Title");
        tipDes = bundle.getString("Des");

title.setText(tipTitle);
        description.setText(tipDes);


        return view;

    }
```

Comment: Please update code you show fragment in 2nd Activity

Comment: Hi Lisha, welcome to StackOverflow. It will be easier to understand your problem if you add the relevant code snippets to your question, such as opening the new activity and handing the back button. Thanks.

Comment: One thing you don't want to do is trying to marry the two activities. There are so many places where the code would go wrong. Try using NavigationComponent to handle navigation. There are millions of way your code will give you hell. You have two activities. When you migrate from the first activity to the next the previous one is killed. Then the second one is loaded when you go back the second one is killed and the first is loaded. The first activity,second activity,the first fragment,the second fragment have different lifecycles. You can't pin point the problem .

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have updated with code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Activities and fragments both have their own lifecycles. When you loaded the second activity. The first activity was killed inorder to make room for the second one. when you press back button the second one is killed and the first is inflated into view. YOu need to go back to your code and simplify your navigation structure or post your navigation code for further assistance. 
Cheers.